# nodejs script freezes after a fixed number of caught errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

After 23 errors the script freezes in the catch block using repairjson module.
Is there a way to clear a cache and reset a limitation somewhere? I tried setting the variable to null but it keeps freezing at that point. The script does not behave the same way on different machines; nodejs does not freeze on my test environment, set up similarly to production.

Here is the code:

```js
const { Client } = require('pg');
const { jsonrepair } = require('jsonrepair')

// Database connection settings
const dbSettings = {
  user: 'postgres',
  password: pw,
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'db',
  port: 5432, 
};

// Create a new PostgreSQL client
const client = new Client(dbSettings);

async function main() {
  try {
    await client.connect();

    // Fetch rows with broken JSON from the database
    const query = "SELECT jsonresponse FROM brokenjson";
    const result = await client.query(query);
    const rows = result.rows;

    // Iterate through rows, repair JSON, and update data
    for (const row of rows) {
      const { obit_sqn, response } = row;

      try {
        const repairedJSON = jsonrepair(response); // Parse the repaired JSON
        console.log(repairedJSON);
        console.log(`${obit_sqn}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    
  } finally {
    await client.end();
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: Are you sure it freezes and is not simply done? There is no `process.exit(0)` at the end of your code so it's possible there is still some handle open internally or something like this, preventing the script from just exiting by itself. Did you use a debugger to step through it?